# Best ways to Improve Sharepoint 2007 Performance?

Tags: performance, sharepoint, moss, vmware

OK we are at the end of our rope here, and I’d really appreciate  feedback from the SO community.

Our basic issue is  slow performance by our MOSS-based intranet--

Some environment info:

We have a MOSS standard edition for a collaboration based site.

- The sitedb is 29 Gb
- we have two  VMWare based front end
  servers. (2x 32bit CPUS each)
- less than 1000 users spread over all
  timezones
- We have one big site
  collection with subsites.

**General symptoms:**
Loading front page and pages that have been ‘warmed-up’ is pretty decent- but pages/sites off the beaten path are very slow to load.

We see spikes, where a page all of a sudden takes 30 seconds to load, vs its more normal 2

Here’s what we have done already:

- Scaled way back on crawling
- enabled object and blob caching
- optimized VMware setup
- followed the Microsoft IT whitepaper on MOSS sharepoint best practice (esp list size etc)

I don’t know what else to do here—Split into multiple site collections?

Switch to 64 bit front-end servers?

Would be great to hear from others who have been in similar situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say how much memory your front end servers have - given that they are 32bit, I'll assume the maximum per worker process of roughly 2gb + change.

My advice? Switch to 64 bit, add more memory, and check that you are not using just one w3wp worker process per front end. Have a dig into "web gardens," that is to say where you configure multiple w3wp processes per front end. To start with, start with two workerprocesses per front end and see how that works out. Also make sure they are set to recycle, and that the recycling of each pair of worker processes do NOT overlap - having two+ workers means they can take turns to recycle without cutting access.

just my 0.02.

-Oisin

Comment: Both front end servers have 4gb ram..  Had looked at web gardens, but I thought MS recommednation was not to use them.. ie msdn reference in this one: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/joelo/archive/2007/10/29/sharepoint-app-pool-settings.aspx

Comment: fair enough, joel is the man. But, he does expand a bit on this. Web gardens MAY help if you have more than one cpu (which you do); if you read down a bit further, he says "try 2, if you don't get more than 15% boost, forget it" or words to that effect. I take it yourd DB is not virtualised.. ;)

Comment: splitting into multiple site collections may help too - but it's painful to do that sometimes depending on your setup. I think the MS recommendation is 20gb per content db iirc...

Comment: "Do not use Web gardens ---

Web gardens are Internet Information Services (IIS) application pools that are supported by multiple worker processes. We recommend that you do not use Web gardens for enterprise content management sites. This is because Web gardens have negative effects on page output caching."

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298550%28office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think your very first task is to determine where the problem actually is - 
until you know that you are wasting your time changing things.

- Is the database server on a separate server or one of your web servers?
- Do you see a CPU/Disk bottleneck on your front end or db servers?
- It sounds like your world wide; do you see the same performance problems from networks close to the server - is it a WAN issue?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for some helpful advice all, one thing I just learned was that our object caching has basically not been doing anything! This is because the way it seems to work is that if you have rights to edit ANYWHERE on the site collection, it per default disables object caching across the portal. Since all users have rights to at least something, this means caching was doing basically nothing!

We discovered this by enabling the cache debugging, which puts a small comment in the html about what cache is being used. After changing the setting "Allow writers to view cached content" in the authenticated cache profile,

We are seeing what this does for editors, but for regular viewers, the anecdotal evidence is that it is having a big impact!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, caching is the best way to reduce load on the system.
Adding RAM to the SQL server is also good. (64 bit is really a must for your SQL server, WFE not so important).

Not sure if you want to recycle the processes though. I have not evidence for this except a conversation with someone saying the recycling the processes looked to have solved one performance issue, but was introducing others.

Did I mention caching?

The SQL server should handle database up to 100Gb, but at that size they will be hard to manage for backups and the like, so splitting your site into relevant site collections is something you may need to plan for now, but this may not be relevant to performance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at [Plan for software boundaries (Office SharePoint Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx)?

At first glance, your server *fits* in their recommended settings.

To improve performance you should take a look at :

- 64-bit servers
- Limiting the number of items displayed in your document lists
  [image: Limiting number of items displayed]
  <sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/Cc262787.1951d88d-7814-41a2-97fc-65e6fab351f7(en-us,TechNet.10).gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check the disk usage. If you have two VMs and they run of the same disk / SAN, make sure it isn't too busy. Overloaded SANs kill performance

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw my hat in the ring and recommend 64 bit as well. Perhaps not as an immediate fix, but going forward, I would put a move to 64 bit as a goal for your entire farm.

I'd also take some issue w/ Nat's comment that it doesn't matter on the Web Front Ends.  I won't debate benchmarks or argue memory addressability.  It's really simpler than that.

Microsoft has publically stated that 2007 is the last version of SharePoint that will run on 32 bit servers.  Going forward 64 bit is going to be a requirement - so like the FRAM oil filter guy says - "pay me now or pay me later"...

Answer (score 0):

we have also performance problems. We upgraded on win 2008 64bit witch make some difference but not as much as expected.

The bih boost gave us changing from NTLM azthentication to Kerberos. This was our major improvement.

hope this helps to someone

Answer (score 0):

I run a very similar setup, however we have over 400GB spread over 3 site collections. There are a few other things you can attempt before going down the 64bit path.

- Ensure there is no Disk or Bandwidth issues between the DB server and web front ends. The network speed to the database server is critical.
- Check the database server itself, if the disks are on a SAN there may be performance issues if there is contention for the phsyical drive on the san. RAM is also important, the more it can cache to memory the less time waiting for disks to respond.
- Schedule crawling jobs to run outside of regular business hours
- You've enabled object caching which can be huge help, be sure to ensure compression is enabled too! For lower bandwidth users sharepoint sends a large amount of CSS information to users that compresses down to 1/10th it's size if compression is enabled.
- Heres another big one, ensure your companies DNS is working correctly in other locations and look into if this problem is related to external sources. IE we have a sonicwall firewall that is brutal on response times for offices connecting through it for anything.
- Micrsoft has a whitepaper on performance counter monitering. It is very thorough and will help you narrow down the problem between CPU/RAM/Network/HD IO.

Hope this helps!